# Maple: parametric plot with implicit parameter function

Tags: plot, maple

I need to plot a parametric curve (p(x), h(x)) with the following conditions:

Given a system of equations for x, y and p, and expression for h(x,y,p)

```
eq1 := 2*sin(x)-p*(cos(x))(2*sin(x)+sin(y)) = 0
eq2 := sin(y)-p*(cos(y))(sin(x)+sin(y)) = 0

h = -2*cos(x)-cos(y)-(1/2)*p(sin(x)^2+(sin(x)+sin(y))^2)
```

I tried eliminating the y variable, and got this (by isolating sin(y), cos(y) and using (sin^2)(y) + (cos^2)(y) = 1):

```
4*((1-p*cos(x))^2)(cos(x)^2+(2-p*cos(x))^2*sin(x)^2) = p^2*((cos^2)(x))(2-p*cos(x))^2

h = -2*cos(x)-(2*(1-p*cos(x)))/p(2-p*cos(x))-(1/2)*p*((sin^2)(x))(1+(1+(2*(1-p*cos(x)))/(p*cos(x)))^2)
```

Hence I have something like parametrization for h and p with the parameter x, but for p(x) it is implicit.

I tried different commands 'solve' for p(x) and each time I got 'Warning, solutions may have been lost' [(here is the screenshot of this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHcIh.jpg). Also, I attempted to plot a "2-D implicit plot" with an "Interactive Plot with 1 parameter" in Plot Builder considering x as slideable parameter (supposing that intervals for p, h and x are known). [Screenshot with Plot Builder settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYRo9.jpg)

The [resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCWLq.jpg) is incorrect, because I want x to be a parameter, running from 0 to 0.1, and this way is giving only plot for one fixed value of x. The code of that attempt in Plot Builder (for some fixed value of slideable x):

```
plots[implicitplot](h = -1.992779349-2*(1-.9963896745*p)/p(2-.9963896745*p)-.3603808272e-2*p, p = .6 .. 5, h = -3 .. -5, labels = [p, h])
```

So, the main point of my question is: how can one plot the parametric curve with such implicit function for p(x)? Is it even possible (I'm using Maple 13)?

Comment: You have included Maple code as plaintext, but as such it appears to be missing some multiplications signs. Eg, between `p` and opening brackets, between closing and opening brackets, etc. As such those  are parsed as function calls rather than multiplication. Yet elsewhere you multiply by `p` alone. And elsewhere you write about calling `solve` on `p(x)`. It's all muddled. You should fix it all up. As written it's almost certainly not what you seem to expect.

Comment: Close examination of the "Plot Command" partially visible in your screenshot  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCWLq.jpg  reveals use of p as mere name as well as within a presumably malformed function call `p(,,,,)` likely intended instead as multiplication. It really looks like your expressions are not what you think they are, as typed into Maple. I believe you need to include missing multiplication symbols in your plaintext code.